# Execute PowerShell as an administrator from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following C# code

```
using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
{
  invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
  // ...
}
```

which gives me the exception

> Access to the registry key
>   'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell'
>   is denied.

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/02/15/execution-policy-and-vista.aspx), the solution is to start PowerShell as an administrator.

Ordinarily, this can be accomplished by right-clicking PowerShell and selecting "Run as Administrator". Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx) out

You need to impersonate as an administrator to do it (you will of course need administrator credentials)

Check that article, that also comes with code ready to use (I've used it and it works great)

Basically, you need to do this:

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
    using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
    {
        invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows Server 2012 and PowerShell 3.0. :(

Comment: I am surprised that the OP marked this as the answer. In the question he states "right-clicking PowerShell and selecting 'Run as Administrator'" which implies that the credentials they are running under is already a member of the administrators group but they are being stopped by the wonderful security (cough, cough) that MS added called UAC. The solution posted (and checked off as) does not address this. Part of me says to mark down this post because the answer does not solve the *posted* question...

Comment: This is very old code from the code project. 2005. It isn't going to work in Windows 2012. I'd have to find some way to convert it to 64 bit.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post, but we ran into this same problem recently.

We had to scope the execution policy on the machine running the C# code by running the following from PowerShell...

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

When we had done this previously, without scoping, we were setting the execution policy for Administrator. Visual Studio \ C# was running as the current user, causing it to fail with insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Administrative privileges are at the *application* level. The app that needs admin access in this case is *yours*. Creating runspaces in C# in a custom app does not invoke powershell the application - it just loads some assemblies into your application.

That said, you can elevate as the other poster said although embedding admin usernames and passwords into source code make me feel ill.

-Oisin

Comment: It doesn't have to ho into the source code, my snippet is just an example

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative model would be to wrap the powershell executor into a simple asp.net webapi webservice.

The webservice could  then be configured to run with the required permissions needed to do it's job. It can provide it's own security to determine which clients can call it.

To execute a script, you would just call webservice methods. You could make the method quite general - script name and params.

It's a bit more work, but a lot more secure (see x0n's thoughts).

Comment: This is more of a hack than an alternative method. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

**Strictly for DEV environment**
This is relatively very old post.
But I have found a new way to do this. 
I am hosting the C# web api on IIS 8 having some powershell code that I want to run with administrator privileges.

So I provided the admin credentials in the Application pool identity setting.

[image: IIS8 on Windows 2012 server]

Just set administrator account in app pool identity.

Hope this helps to anyone. :)

Comment: Always avoid this, because this is serious security lack

Comment: its much better than keeping credentials hard coded ... :)
@devi -  think about it once

Comment: not agreed, running iis pool as local administrator is very poor idea, nothing another cannot be more bad, even hardcode. 
In general case, requirement to running something as local admin in web application is signal to poor design.

Comment: IMO on a dev machine that's fine, but on a production machine, not so much.