# How to run a PowerShell script from C# as non-elevated user

Tags: c#, security, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script from a C# application and I need the script to run when my C# app is running as a non-admin user (e.g. Network Service or some other domain account).

Previously, I was using the following code:

```
using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
{
    // load the powershell module
    invoker.Invoke("Import-Module MyModule");

    // run the cmdlet defined in the module 
    invoker.Invoke("MyCmdlet");
}
```

I don't know whether this is the best approach for running cmdlets defined in a module (please teach me if there's a better way!).  In any case, this works perfectly if I'm running as an administrative user.  I tried running this as Network Service, however, and I got an unfriendly error in the constructor of RunspaceInvoke:

**Requested registry access is not allowed.**

Is there a way I can run my PowerShell cmdlets as a non-elevated user such as Network Service?  I do not need or desire to access the registry.  The cmdlet itself also does not require elevated privileges.

Answer (score 2):

We use a version of the below. The "script" parameter is the PS script to run. We use this from a custom command line so that we can mix c# commands with some written in PS. "results" can be used to capture the evaluation of your script. The "out-default" line means that the output of the PS script is written to the console. A version of this can instead capture the output to a TextBox or similar if you have a WinForm of WPF app.

```
public void run(string script)
{
    IEnumerable<PSObject> results;
    var config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    var host = new ScriptHost();
    using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(host, config))
    {
        runspace.Open();
        runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("prog", this);

        using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptPath))
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(string.Format("$env:path = \"{0};\" + $env:path", scriptPath));

            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);

            var outDefault = new Command("out-default");
            outDefault.MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
            pipeline.Commands.Add(outDefault);

            results = pipeline.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

more on lkaso answer

this shows you how to run it as anybody, not just admin. YOu have to run it as somebody, the service is running as a heavily restricted account that cannot do anything.

or run the service itself as joe user

Answer (score 0):

Can you use SysInternals [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) tool to see what Registry access it's trying to accomplish?  Maybe that will give you some insight as to what you could do to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313673/execute-powershell-as-an-administrator-from-c/1313679) entry will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to elevate or impersonate.  I'm trying to run PowerShell scripts as a *low-privileged* user, not a high-privileged user.