# Running a powershell script through c#

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

I have a couple of problems.  here's how it works.  on a windows form, the user clicks the button.  the button executes a cmd script and in turn the cmd script executes a powershell script.

why the cmd script you ask?  well, if I have a click of the button run a powershell script I have problems with signing.

At the beginning of the powershell script I set the execution policy to unrestricted.  if i run the script through powershell directly, this changes the execution policy perfectly fine and the script works.  if i have the user click the button to run the powershell script, it says I have problems with signing, even though the execution policy did get set to unrestricted!  ridiculous.  I found that setting the execution policy within the cmd script fixed this and that is how i run my powershell scripts at the click of a button.  whatever, it was a work around and it works.

my problem now is I have a cmd script that calls a powershell script to change a registry key.  this is done yet again by the click of a button.  it looks fine, everything seems to work, but the value of the key does not get changed.  now, if I simply run the cmd script without my windows form application, the value of the key does change.  why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the automation.runspaces namespace has caused me a lot of problems.  i am a student, i work at a college.  i am using college computers and the college domain.  a long story short, ive abandonded using runspaces and i simply open powershell in c# and execute the script.  that hasnt worked so i wrote some  cmd scripts.  here is an example that works:

Powershell Script:

## Rename to the Mac Address

```
$OS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
$NIC = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where{$_.IPEnabled -eq “TRUE”}
$PC = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem 

if($NIC.MacAddress -eq $null)
    {
    Write-Host "No Network Connection! The PC will not be renamed until the network is enabled"
    }
else
    {
    $MacAddress = $NIC.MacAddress
    $NewPCName = "PC-" + $MacAddress.Substring(0) -replace ':'

    $PC.Rename($NewPCName) 

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "New PC Name"
    $NewPCName
    }
    write-Host "The PC has been renamed and will restart in 5 seconds."
    start-sleep -s 5
    restart-computer
```

if I run the above script in powershell it works.  if I use Process.Start(powershell.exe, "C:\myscript"); in c# it does not run.  even setting the execution policy does not help.  so I use a cmd script as follows:

cmd Script:

powershell -noexit -executionpolicy unrestricted "C:\myscript.ps1"

and it executes.

now I have the following:

Powershell script:

Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -name AutoAdminLogon -value 0
write-host "Changing Registry"
Start-Sleep -s 10

cmd Script:

powershell -noexit -executionpolicy unrestricted "C:\Windows\ITS\ChangeRegistry.ps1"

in my windows form program i have a button click event call the cmd script.  it looks like it works, nothing crashes, the cmd executes as it should, its writes to the host, it sleeps for 10 seconds.  but the registry key never changes.  but my first example of the powershell rename script and cmd works perfectly with the click of a button on a windows form.  so i just dont get it.

Answer (score 3):

I think your actual question is "How do I invoke a Powershell script from C#, and make sure it runs with administrative privileges?"

The answer is "impersonation":

- [Execute PowerShell as an administrator from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313673/execute-powershell-as-an-administrator-from-c-sharp)