# Calling Restart-Computer in Powershell core in .net 3.1 credential error but working in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, asp.net-core

I`m trying to convert this code which works in Powershell ISE

```
PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd???" -AsPlainText -Force

$User = "testing\administrator"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

Restart-Computer -ComputerName 10.0.50.235 -Credential $Credential -Force
```

Below is what I have in a console app written in .net core 3.1 but gives a WinRm error.

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Restart-Computer");

SecureString secureString = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "P@ssw0rd???", "testing").SecurePassword;
PSCredential psc = new PSCredential($"testing\\administrator", secureString);
ps.AddParameter("Credential", psc);
ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", ip);
ps.AddParameter("Force");
var results = ps.Invoke();
```

When I run this the error is thrown

> Failed to restart the computer 10.0.50.235 with the following error message: The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config.

I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong as it works fine in Powershell ISE but not in .net.

I've also tried the following but i still get the same error

```
SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in rebootOptions.Password)
{
    secureString.AppendChar(c);
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you're connecting to powershell as a remote host, thus it's not allowing you... check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517105/how-to-run-powershell-from-c-sharp-as-administrator) on how to run as administrator ... however, I'm not sure this works on .net core

Comment: Are you sure you are doing the same? ISE uses Powershell for Windows, .net core usually uses Powershell Core. The trusted host config you have in ps for Windows might be different.