# are there any restrictions of runningPowerShell Methods on IIS web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, powershell

I want to run PowerCLI scripts inside my asp.net mvc web application. so i have installed the PowerCLI application inside my application server. then i wrote the following test action method, and i run the web application inside my visual studio and everything worked well:-

```
public ActionResult About(string vCenterIp = "****", string vCenterUsername = "****", string vCenterPassword = "****")
        {


var shell = PowerShell.Create();



                string PsCmd = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" + vCenterIp + "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword + "';" + System.Environment.NewLine;



                PsCmd = PsCmd + "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;


                PsCmd = PsCmd + "Get-VMHost" + System.Environment.NewLine;



                shell.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd);

                var results = shell.Invoke();




                if (results.Count > 0)
```

now my question will i be ale to run the above action method when i deploy my web application to an IIS ? as from my reading seems IIS by defualt does not allow to run EXE scripts .. so are there any restrictions or concerns i need to take case of before deploying my application to an IIS since i am running powerCLI scripts inside it ?

Comment: Definitely. Web applications don't run with any real privileges, and you don't want them to. You want them to run with the least privileges possible to avoid attacks. You will either need to have the application pool that IIS runs within use an account with the proper rights, or use impersonation. If this website is in any way exposed to the general internet then this could become an attack vector.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick this will not be exposed to internet directly, as this is an internal system , and our company users can only access the system (of course only authorized users can call the action methods that run the powercli scripts),, but in all cases i found many example that show how to run powershell scripts inside asp.net web applications,, so should this be always avoided ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's someone else who has attempted what you're doing....

http://jeffmurr.com/blog/?p=142...

I love the last bit...

> To run this on a server, the ApplicationPool hosting your application
>   will have to have administrator rights.

It really depends on your organization and where you intend to deploy this site.  For many businesses, running anything on a web server with admin privileges would be completely unacceptable.

I'd try and avoid this if you can, perhaps have a separate windows service which communicates with the web site using a database as an intermediary, i.e. the web site sticks a job in the database, the windows service processes it securely, posts the results to SQL Server, the user can view the results on another page which reads the data written.

If that sounds like too much effort, I'd at least use this approach...

[Execute PowerShell as an administrator from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313673/execute-powershell-as-an-administrator-from-c-sharp)

...to create a site that runs with normal (reduced) privileges and temporarily elevates it's privileges to run the powershell script